# Can you help me to figure out "that of"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, that

"English grammar has been closely bound up with that of Latin since the 16th century, when English first began to be taught in schools."

I have no idea of "that of" in this sentence.
Can anyone example the grammar and usage for me?

Answer (score 1):

In this case *that of* means "**the grammar of** [Latin]". It is used as a substitute to avoid repetition of the same word (grammar) twice.